# How to prove by induction that a sequence is bounded

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, induction

I know how the basics of mathematical induction works, but I don't know how to prove that a sequence is bounded

The sequence is given recursively

$$a_1= \sqrt{2}$$
$$a_{n+1} = \sqrt{2+a_n}$$

I should prove that the sequence is rising and it has an upper bound of 5.

Comment: Prove instead that $2$ is an upper bound.

Comment: For boundedness below, you need only note every term is nonnegative.

Comment: I hope it's clear that $a_1<5$. If $a_n<5$ then $a_{n+1}<\sqrt{2+5}$. Is $\sqrt{2+5}<5$?

Comment: @AnginaSeng This part doesn't make sense to me. $a_{n+1} < \sqrt{2 + 5}$

Answer (score 1):

Base case, $n=1$: $a_1=\sqrt{2}\leq5$. This is true.

Suppose that $a_n\leq 5$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

$$a_{n+1}=\sqrt{2+a_n}\leq\sqrt{2+5}=\sqrt{7}$$

Suppose $\sqrt{7}>5$. That implies $7>25$, which is false, so the assumption that $\sqrt{7}>5$ is false and we can conclude that $\sqrt{7}\leq5$. This shows that $a_{n+1}\leq 5$, and we can close the induction.

To show that the sequence is increasing, we could use a function or use induction again. I will use induction.

Base case, $n=1$: $a_2=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}} > \sqrt{2}=a_1$. The base case is true.

Now assume that $a_n>a_{n-1}$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

$$a_{n+1}=\sqrt{2+a_n}$$  $$a_n=\sqrt{2+a_{n-1}} $$

By our induction hypothesis, $$\sqrt{2+a_n}> \sqrt{2+a_{n-1}}\Longrightarrow a_{n+1}>a_n$$
and we can close the induction.

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense.

Comment: Additional question: How would you prove that the sequence is increasing?

Comment: @5arg I updated the answer to include the increasing part.

Answer (score 1):

**Sketch**:

Consider the function used to define the sequence:
$\;f(x)=\sqrt{x+2}$. This is an increasing function, defined on $[-2,+\infty)$ and the equation $f(x)=x$ has a single solution: $x=2$, which is the limit of the sequence if it is convergent.

Now since $f$ is increasing and continuous, $f\bigl([0,2]\bigr)=[f(0),f(2)]=[\sqrt 2,2]$. Hence, by a trivial induction, $\; a_n \le 2\quad\forall n\in\mathbf N$.